# SQL modify value of columns through addition

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add to each row in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074355/how-do-i-add-to-each-row-in-mysql)

This is probably really easy for most of you but I can't wrap my head around it.  I have a column in my table that is of type Float.  I want to modify the value of this column for each row by adding 15.  For example, if the column's value for a particular row is 10, I want to add 15 to it to make the new value 25, and the same for each subsequent row.

I am attempting to use PHP to do this but is there a way to do this just straight SQL?

Comment: Dup. of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074355/how-do-i-add-to-each-row-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `tableName` SET `fieldName` = `fieldName` + 15
```